# The New Method for Symmetric NAT traversal

Tags: methods, new-operator, nat, symmetric

Has anyone implemented the technique found and described by the Japanees researchers for symmetric NAT traversal at [The New Method for Symmetric NAT traversal](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228411948_A_New_Method_for_Symmetric_NAT_Traversal_in_UDP_and_TCP) ? specifically, can existing STUN servers be used in place of S1 and S2 or does it require developing and setting up these servers anew? Also how are short TTLs implemented into the large packets sent from EchoServer to EchoClient that reach NAT b but don't reach S2 ?

Thank you